# How to setup WebSocket Secure connection with PHP?

Tags: php, html, websocket

I can't find any information about setting up a wss connection in PHP.
I have no problem to be connected throw ws. I'm using this pretty great library to do this by the way: https://github.com/albeva/php-websocket

But my website use https and I need a WebSocket Secure connection to avoid Firefox to complain about the fact that the connection is insecure.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

**Edit**

Here is the code used by the library to start the socket connection:

```
$master = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if (!is_resource($master)) {
    $this->throwSocketError();
}

// set options
if (!socket_set_option($master, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {
    $this->throwSocketError();
}

// bind
if (!socket_bind($master, $this->host, $this->port)) {
    $this->throwSocketError();
}

// listen for connections
if (!socket_listen($master, SOMAXCONN)) {
    $this->throwSocketError();
}
```

I believe I need to change this code but I can't find how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best shot on PHP is currently to use [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). The best way to setup an wss connection, is to put your websocket server behind Nginx or HAProxy which will handle all the SSL stuff for you. This is explained [here](http://socketo.me/docs/deploy) with HAProxy. Note that you can do the same with Nginx since it also now support WebSocket.

Comment: I find stunnel a simple way to SSLize insecure services.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try [stream_socket_server](http://php.net/stream_socket_server) ?

```
<?php
$socket = stream_socket_server("ssl://0.0.0.0:".$port, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket) {
  echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
  while ($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
    fwrite($conn, 'some data...\n');
    fclose($conn);
  }
  fclose($socket);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example (and link), which was modified slightly, and found from another SO post.
[Link to other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051232/cant-connect-to-ssl-web-service-with-ws-security-using-php-soap-extension-cer)

And here is a link to the stream_context_create php function definition.
[function definition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)

```
try 
{ 
    $localCertificateFilespec = $connection['localCertificateFilespec']; 
    $localCertificatePassphrase = $connection['localCertificatePassphrase']; 

    $sslOptions = array( 
        'ssl' => array( 
            'local_cert' => $localCertificateFilespec, 
            'passphrase' => $localCertificatePassphrase, 
            'allow_self_signed' => true, 
            'verify_peer' => false 
        ) 
    ); 
    $sslContext = stream_context_create($sslOptions); 

    $clientArguments = array( 
        'stream_context' => $sslContext, 
        'local_cert' => $localCertificateFilespec, 
        'passphrase' => $localCertificatePassphrase, 
        'trace' => true, 
        'exceptions' => true, 
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1 
    ); 

    $oClient = new WSSoapClient($connection['wsdlFilespec'], $clientArguments); 
    $oClient->__setUsernameToken($connection['username'], $connection['password']); 

    return $oClient->__soapCall($operation, $request); 
}
```

**However**, at the very bottom of the linked SO post, you will find an answer from "Sam".  I am needing to do this same thing in the next few weeks, so I plan on using Sams method... as I am more of a fan of CURL within PHP.

Comment: I've updated my post to show the start function (which use the php socket extension) of the library I'm using. I had already read the post you're pointing out but wasn't able to make it work with this code.